# Can I keep this (Celosia) plant outside?

Tags: identification

(Note: I'll update the title if possible when I know what plant this actually is)

I have a plant outside but I'm starting to wonder if that's the best idea as they are starting to grow/survive in different ways. I tried finding out what kind of plant this is, but I have no tags on it and not enough knowledge to find out otherwise.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "cockscomb". It is a type of Celosia,  [Celosia cristata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celosia_argentea_var._cristata), also called "brain celosia".

Wikipedia says, "The plants are hardy and resistant to most diseases, and grow equally well indoors or out, though the perfect place is one with no shade and a well-drained soil, as the plant is susceptible to fungal diseases."

Of course Wikipedia doesn't know where you live, but I'm pretty sure I have seen it growing outdoors in *my* area (though not in my own garden). But the climate is pretty mild here.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is indeed a match. Looking at the catalog from the place where I got them, it's exactly as listed there (but no pictures so I couldn't match it before).